# Test Class for a Wrapper class when Checkbox is true

Tags: apex, unit-test

My Apex Class is

```
      Public class Myclass{

  public class tempconwrapper{
    public boolean selectedcheck;
    public void setselectedcheck(boolean b){this.selectedcheck = b;}
    public boolean getselectedcheck(){return selectedcheck;}
      public Temporary_Contact__c tempcon{get;set;}
      public tempconwrapper(temporary_contact__c temporary){
         tempcon= temporary;
         selectedcheck=false;     
        }

      }
      public list<tempconwrapper> gettemporarycontactlist(){
      list<tempconwrapper> tempwrapperlist=new list<tempconwrapper>();
      list<Temporary_contact__c> TemporaryList = [select  id,Name,First_Name__c,Last_Name__c,Email__c,contact_list__c,Installment__c,Sno__c,Check_temp__c,Map_Contact__c,OrderNumber__c,Recurring__c,Xmldata__c,Master_Transaction_Number__c from Temporary_contact__c  order by createddate desc  ];
      for(Temporary_Contact__c  tempconlist: TemporaryList ){
        tempwrapperlist.add(new tempconwrapper(tempconlist));
     }
      return wrapperlist;
     }

     public pagereference processtempcon(){
      set<Temporary_contact__c> tempconset = new set<Temporary_contact__c>();
           for(tempconwrapper temp: gettemporarycontactlist()){             
                     if(temp.selectedcheck == true) { //this Value is always false in the     constructor
                        //my code                                       
                      }                   
                  }     
          return null;      
        }
     }
```

How can I make `if(temp.selectedcheck == true)` to true so that it can cover my code

```
My test class is 

 myclass temporary = new myclass();
 Temporary_Contact__c tc = new      Temporary_Contact__c(OrderNumber__c='1321161610784412',First_Name__c='First',Last_Name__c='Last',Map_Contact__c=con.id,Installment__c=2,Check_Temp__c=true,Master_Transaction_Number__c='1210111712415518392');
insert tc;                
 batchtemporarycls.tempconwrapper tempclass = new batchtemporarycls.tempconwrapper(tc);  
 tempclass.getselectedcheck();
 tempclass.setselectedcheck(true);
 temporary.gettemporarycontactlist();
```

Comment: I dont see setter in your code .You need to invoke the setter method in test class for your implementation

Comment: i am not sure without setter how your functionality working.The wrapper has to be set i believe.                   tempclass.tempconwrapper tmp=new tempclass.tempconwrapper();    tmp.selectedcheck=true;      try the above example and i hope it sets as per your code .

Comment: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class                   A good wiki article on wrapper class .Its very clear on how a wrapper is used as getter ,setter

Comment: @MohithKumar  'tmp.selectedcheck=true' giving the same Result....:(

Comment: Please include a setter method for wrapper.

Comment: The first line of your test class also needs to start with `@test`

Comment: @MohithKumar Added a setter Method and modified the test code.But no change

Answer (score 2):

I think your "MyClass" needs to have a public list of tempconfwrappers with {get;set;}. The getter will just return the list not compute it.

The list is initialized in the constructor of "MyClass" (which you have to add)

EDIT:
Following an example of class and of test which covers the described situation. The test proves that it is possible indeed to enter that "if":) Always assert in tests, coverage itself is meaningless.

```
public class MyClass{


//the wrapper
public class Wrapper {

    public boolean selectedCheck {get;set;}
    public Integer someValue {get;set;}
    public Wrapper(Integer someValue){
        this.someValue=someValue;
        this.selectedCheck = false;

    }
}

//the list of wrappers
public List<Wrapper> wrapperList {get;set;}

//class constructor
public MyClass(){
    //e.g. loading some data
    List <Integer> loadData = new Integer[]{1,2,3};

    //populating the list:
    wrapperList = new Wrapper[]{};
    for(Integer i : loadData){
        wrapperList.add(new Wrapper(i));
    }
}

//utility method
public String process(){
    String outcome = 'outside the if';
    for(Wrapper w : this.wrapperList){
        //I will use the "outcome" string to test that the code was reached indeed.
        if(w.selectedCheck){
            outcome='inside the if';

        }    
    }

    return outcome;

}


}
```

You can write and run a proper test class as follows:

```
@isTest 
private class TestMyClass {
    static testMethod void validateTestMyClass() {

       //this call tests the constructor:
       MyClass temp = new MyClass();

       //test building was complete
       System.assert(temp.wrapperList.size()==3);
       System.assert(temp.wrapperList[0].selectedCheck==false);

       //manipulate
       temp.wrapperList[0].selectedCheck=true;

       //execute process method
       String outcome = temp.process();

       //test that the method entered in the if sentece:
       System.assert(outcome=='inside the if');

    }
}
```

Note: if it's a constructor and getters are used in the visualforce page with ajax calls.. things may need some more work to get on going!

Comment: It didn't covered the condition...

Comment: ..ok, tweaked the code, now it's very explicit:)